# How to find the Lowest Common Ancestor in a Binary Tree (Not Binary Search Tree) ITERATIVELY in Linear time and Constant Space

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I have the following working code to find the LCA for a Binary Tree (not BST) recursively on O(n) time and since I use recursion, in O(n) space.

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class LCA {
    public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        if(root == null) return null;
        if(p == root || q == root) return root;

        TreeNode L = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
        TreeNode R = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);

        // Check 1
        // if one of p or q is in left subtree and other is in right subtree
        // then root is the LCA.
        if(L != null && R != null) return root;

        // Check 2
        // else if L is not null, L is LCA. because p and q both are in left subtree
        // else, LCA is in R as p and q are in right subtree
        return L != null ? L : R;
    }
}
```

**However, I need to do this iteratively in O(n) time and O(1) space.
I have the following code but it uses list to save the two paths that makes it O(n) time and O(n) space**

```
public class LCA {
    List<List<TreeNode>> bothPaths = new ArrayList<List<TreeNode>>();
    public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        if(p == root || q == root) return root;

        findPaths(root, new ArrayList<TreeNode>(), p);
        findPaths(root, new ArrayList<TreeNode>(), q);

        List<TreeNode> listP = bothPaths.get(0);
        List<TreeNode> listQ = bothPaths.get(1);
        int len = Math.min(listP.size(), listQ.size());

        TreeNode previous = null;

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
            if(listP.get(i) == listQ.get(i)){
                previous = listP.get(i);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        return previous; // common element between 2 list
    }

    private void findPaths(TreeNode root, ArrayList<TreeNode> tempList, TreeNode temp){
        if(root == null) return;

        tempList.add(root);

        if(root == temp){
            bothPaths.add(tempList);
            return;
        }

        findPaths(root.left, new ArrayList<TreeNode>(tempList),temp);
        findPaths(root.right, new ArrayList<TreeNode>(tempList), temp);
    }
}
```

**I want to know if any O(n) time and O(1) space ITERATIVE algorithm exists to do this?**

Comment: Go up from p and q iteratively unless you reach the top. Record all found nodes into a set. Intersect these sets.

Comment: Thanks @StepanYakovenko for the solution. However, I need the one which uses Constant space. This solution is similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Go up from **p** unless you reach a top. This will give you **depth_p** of **p** node. Do the same to get **depth_p**. Then you will have **depth_p** and **depth_q**. Let **l** be lowest of **p** and **q** and **h** be highest of them. Go up from **l** to |**depth_p** - **depth_q**| levels. This new node together with **h** will give you two nodes of the same level. Go up together from from these two nodes and they will meet at the common parent.[image]

PS: if you don't have parent pointer, then you can play with sending iterators of speed 1 and 1/2 from left and right side. One of this iterators will reach another in some common node, you can use it later as root node.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have parent pointers, go up from p and q to the root to compute their depth in the tree, say m and n. Then, go up from p and q to the root in lockstep, one level at a time, until the node is the same for both searches, but first go up |m-n| levels in the tree for whichever of p and q are further from the root.

Comment: Parent pointer is not there so this solution does not work. I know the variant of solution that you are suggesting that uses parent pointer(if its there in node structure) and do the same kind of logic which is similar to finding out the junction point of two linked list.